# When did Joel Spolsky Talk About Approving Some Features for Managers

Tags: discussion, joel-spolsky

I really tried to search his articles and the podcast transcripts but I can't come up with the right keyword combination.

I'm looking for the quote when Joel says something about some report feature on programmer's metrics for managers, he was upset wanted to know who approved the feature and it turned out the he had approved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if he talked about it in the podcast, but he certainly mentioned it on his blog: 
[Amnesia](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/12/10.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.